# How to sort quoted strings from a text file in Java

Tags: java, performance, sorting

I am trying to read list of quoted strings e.g

```
"GJKFMN","OUYTV","VFRN","APLUI","DCFUYT","DXSER","JHGF","PIUYT","XSQ"
```

from a text file and sort the words on alphabetical order. I also want to score each of these words in form of say `A=1, B=2,...` and sum the alphabets of each word.

I have tried this code below for the sorting but it's not sorting it for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String filePath = null;
    if (args[0] == null || args[0].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Names File Path Enclosed in Double Quotes");
    }
    else {
        filePath = args[0];
    }
    List<String> bufferList = loadDataUsingBufferReader(filePath);
    List<String> listWithoutQuotes = removeQuotes(bufferList);
    listWithoutQuotes.parallelStream().map(String::toUpperCase).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
}
public static List<String> removeQuotes(List<String> listWithQoutes) {
    listWithQoutes = listWithQoutes.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\"", "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return listWithQoutes;
}
public static List<String> loadDataUsingBufferReader(String filePath) {
    final Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), ENCODING));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

In the code I'm reading the file path from command line. When I hard code the input it sorts it but when I read from a file it doesn't. Performance is a key factor as the file could be as large as containing millions of words.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: I'd be curious if your Java 8 streams approach to sorting was any more efficient than a simple `Collections.sort(lst, new SortIgnoreCase());`, where class "SortIgnoreCase()" does a "toLowerCase().compareTo()"

Comment: It is not correct to talk about "the most efficient" algorithm if what you implemented doesn't work at all. I have adjusted the title so that it more precisely reflects what you are actually asking.

Comment: To the solution: I would suggest that you don't use stream until you get some experience with programming. Why? Because debugging of streams can be very hard compared to the normal loops. If you rewrite your code with normal loops and look in the debugger the values of your objects, you will the the reason of the problem.

Comment: @paulsm4 I see what you are saying but the file is large and is it wrong to say that stream api will be faster in processing large files since it applies parallelism?

Comment: @mentallurg the reason why I'm using stream api is because of performance since the file is quite large

Comment: @user1529823: There should not be a noticeable difference. The purpose of streams has nothing to do with performance, but with reducing the boiler plate code. Have you compared performance with and without streams? How big was the difference?

Comment: Q:  is it wrong to say that stream api will be faster in processing large files since it applies parallelism?  A: Yes, that is an incorrect statement.  Java 8 streams are good, they're powerful, and they have many important uses.  But making the file load "faster" just because of the word "parallel" - No!.  That's like saying of "classic" Java: "more threads make the program go faster."  That's simply not true.  It also conflates "speed" vs. "responsiveness" (although your example probably improves neither).

Answer (score 1):

Using the following test data, which you just can copy-paste into a text file and use it as a sample file

```
"DSRD","KJHT","BFXXX","OUYTP"
"ABCD","XSHTKK","RTZI","HKLOPQ"
"BGTSZ","ASY","LOMCV","DESRAW"
"VMWEE","ERTZU","GSDFX","BHGFD"
"CD","FRTZU","JUHL","RETZ"
```

Something like below should work. I hope the method names are self explanatory and it is clear what happens in each step. I have included some println statements as a little debugging help. You should remove them if you are working with your original files which are possibly very large.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String filePath = null;
        if (args[0] == null || args[0].isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter the Names File Path Enclosed in Double Quotes");
        }
        else {
            filePath = args[0];
        }

        List<String> allLines = readAllLinesFromFile(filePath);
        allLines.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("**********************");

        List<String> listWithoutQuotes = removeQuotes(allLines);
        listWithoutQuotes.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("*****************");

        List<String> allWords = getAllWordsFromEachLineSorted(listWithoutQuotes);
        System.out.println(allWords);
        System.out.println("****************");

        List<Integer> scores = calculateStoreForAList(allWords);
        System.out.println(scores);
    }
    static List<String> readAllLinesFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
        return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
    }
    public static List<String> removeQuotes(List<String> listWithQoutes) {
        return listWithQoutes.stream()
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\"", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    public static List<String> getAllWordsFromEachLineSorted(List<String> lines) {
        return lines.stream()
                .map(s -> s.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static int calculateScore(String word){
        return word.chars()
                .map(i -> i-64)
                .sum();
    }
    static List<Integer> calculateStoreForAList(List<String> allWords){
        return allWords.stream()
                .map(str -> calculateScore(str))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

You should see something similar to

```
"DSRD","KJHT","BFXXX","OUYTP"
"ABCD","XSHTKK","RTZI","HKLOPQ"
"BGTSZ","ASY","LOMCV","DESRAW"
"VMWEE","ERTZU","GSDFX","BHGFD"
"CD","FRTZU","JUHL","RETZ"
**********************
DSRD,KJHT,BFXXX,OUYTP
ABCD,XSHTKK,RTZI,HKLOPQ
BGTSZ,ASY,LOMCV,DESRAW
VMWEE,ERTZU,GSDFX,BHGFD
CD,FRTZU,JUHL,RETZ
*****************
[ABCD, ASY, BFXXX, BGTSZ, BHGFD, CD, DESRAW, DSRD, ERTZU, FRTZU, GSDFX, HKLOPQ, JUHL, KJHT, LOMCV, OUYTP, RETZ, RTZI, VMWEE, XSHTKK]
****************
[10, 45, 80, 74, 27, 7, 70, 45, 90, 91, 60, 79, 51, 49, 65, 97, 69, 73, 68, 93]
```

Comment: Even the 2nd one is not sorting it for me.

Comment: it also works for me when I hard code the example data but doesn't work when I try to read them from a txt file. Can you try to read from a text file please and see if it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you removed double quotes from your text file, I would go with following steps;

Reading whole file as one string:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(directory, filename);
String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Split the content into words since you have standard delimiter comma:

```
String[] words = fileContent.split(",");
```

Then sort it by using Arrays class built-in method:

```
Arrays.sort(words);
```

To calculate each word's score: capital "A" ascii decimal value is 65, so if you subtract 64 from each letters' ascii decimal value, you will find the score. For example:

```
String abc = "ABC";
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < abc.length(); ++i){
    sum += (int) abc.charAt(i) - 64;
}
```

Here `sum` value is 6.